# C++ code documentation generation tool

Tags: html, c++, source-code, documentation-viewer, documentation-generator

I want to automatically generate HTML documents for C++ code and have used Doxygen in the past, but if I, for example, look at the NVIDIA [CUDA documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/index.html), there must be better tools ;-)

Does anyone know a document generation tool with comparable quality. Wikipedia has a [large comparison page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators) but it is so large that it fails to be useful for a recommendation.

Comment: With all respect Steve, but your question also *fails to be useful for a recommendation*. If you do not give criteria that the software needs to match, how can anyone make a recommendation? Just pointing to the NVidia example is not enough.

Comment: @Steve check this out http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/, http://www.doxys.dk/doxys_homepage/index.html

Comment: Can you tell us what you don't like about the NVIDIA documentation? Are there any features which are "must have" or "nice to have"? It's difficult to recommend when we don't know hat you are looking for.

Comment: Personally, I don't see it as being so much better than Doxygen. But, if you won't give us a list of requirements, an o/s, or a budget, then we can only suggest that you use whatever NVDIA used. I don't see any mention of it on the page, but you could always contact them at their feedback link (mailto:cudatools@nvidia.com?subject=CUDA Toolkit Documentation Feedback: cuRAND), ask what they use and if it is FOSS.

Comment: OK, this is 6 months old and Steve can't be bothered to improve it.  Downvoting as low quality recommendation request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can strongly recommend [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) Document generator - for an example site take a look at the [new wxPython documentation](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/functions.html).

Generates documentation from:

- Python code
- C/C++ code
- reStructuredText[3](http://docutils.sf.net/rst.html)
- Multiple output formats - HTML (including Windows HTML Help), LaTeX (for printable PDF versions), ePub, Texinfo, manual pages, plain text
- Code Highlighting for a wide range of languages
- Themes
- Index & TOC Generation

Free and cross platform.

Comment: Your link is to a Wiki - does Sphinx generate that as well (or feeds content into an existing wiki)? Also, how is it different/better than doxygen?

Comment: Sphinx generates the wxPython documentation & wiki AFAIK - the OP said that they "didn't like" the look of the Doxygen generated documents - Sphinx has a number of more modern templates out of the box and lots of customisation options.